# Criar variavel com o conteudo de outra variavel

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou precisando criar uma variável porem o nome dela tem que ser o conteúdo de outra já criada.

Exemplo:

```
var nome = "teste";
```

Agora usando o valor da variável nome que é "teste" preciso criar automaticamente uma variável teste

Answer (score 2):

Não é uma prática muito comum. O objetivo de definir uma variável é poder usar seu conteúdo posteriormente. Se você cria essa variável de forma dinâmica, vai precisar acessar seu conteúdo de forma dinâmica também o que não é muito prático.

O que você pode fazer é criar um mapa dinamicamente.

Por exemplo.

```
var nome = 'teste';
var mapa = {};

mapa[nome] = 123;

console.log(mapa);
// Retorna { teste: 123 }
```

Se realmente quiser definir o nome da variável dinamicamente, pode usar o `eval`, mas é uma péssima prática.

```
var nome = 'teste';
texto = nome + ' = ' + '123';

// Como estamos gerando o nome dinamicamente, precisamos
// adicionar um try catch para capturar possíveis nomes inválidos
try {
  eval(texto);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}

console.log(teste);
// Retorna 123
```

Comment: Não esquece de colocar um try catch no eval, caso não seja um nome de variável válido.

Comment: @Mathias opa, bem lembrado :)